# Clickable li's with different number of text lines inside

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to render clickable li's but independent from the content that there is inside of the li. For example the code below has one button with just one line and another one with four lines:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">jkfasdf</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">jkffasdf fjaskdfasfs jajklfd fjklasdfas</a></li>
</ul>

ul{
  background: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  float: left; 
}

li {
  padding: 10px; display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
li:first-child {border-left: none;}

a {

}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tirengarfio/y3NCq/19/).

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks how to convert to clickable the hole li's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display:block` to `a` tag and give `padding` to a tag instead of `li`

```
a {
  display:block; padding: 10px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y3NCq/24/)**

Comment: Not working exactly right, but keep trying. You're almost there!